# Tomcat uses a JRE_HOME that doesn't exist

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay

I'm back to a legacy system (Liferay 5.2 bundled with Tomcat 6 running on JRE 1.6) on Windows to make a small tweak. There are multiple JREs installed on my machine. I set `JRE_HOME` environment variable so Tomcat uses JRockit 1.6 installed on, say, `C:\Program Files\JRockit`. But when I run `startup.bat`, Tomcat output on the console shows its `JRE_HOME` has been set to a directory that doesn't exist at all! I echoed `JRE_HOME` ON PowerShell and it was correct but Tomcat doesn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually found the solution. I write it here hoping to save your time. There is an optional file called `setenv.bat` (also `setenv.sh` for Linux systems) in `[tomcat]\bin` that you can set environment variables used by Tomcat like `JRE_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME`, etc. in it. Tomcat first reads that file to find the required environment variables and if it doesn't find one then it uses the system environment variables. I figured out that `JRE_HOME` had been set in my `setenv.bat` file wrongly. I deleted it from the file and the problem was resolved.